# Localhost 3000 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm learning ruby on rails but all of a sudden localhost/3000 is not working, it was working fine moments ago. I'm using windows 8 and my ruby version is 2.2.4 and rails version is 4.2.6

Rails server is running but localhost/300 is not loading in browser. Help please.
[rails server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is8K8.png)
[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdbcA.png)

Comment: Try to connect to `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Did you run your rails server using rails server -b 0.0.0.0?  Might need this if you are accessing rails from a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `/3000` instead of `:3000`. You need `http://localhost:3000` which connects to localhost using port 3000.

It does actually indicate the correct URL in your console output.

Comment: Thanks you very much Shadwell. I didn't noticed that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the server on a port and it is `3000` so the address should be `http://localhost:3000` instead of `http://localhost/3000`. 
Ports are followed by : in the url